# Make XSLT and XML Output to a XML File

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a few problems with XSLT.

I have this XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTest.xsl"?>
<pages>
  <page>
      <title>New Title</title>
      <id>4782</id>
      <timestamp>2012-09-13 13:15:33</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>kf</username>
        <id>2</id>
      </contributor>
      <text xml:space="preserve"> 
      some text
    </text>
 </page>
 </pages>
```

and this XSL File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="pages/page">
    <content>
       <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
       <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
       <created><xsl:value-of select="timestamp"/></created>
       <created_by><xsl:value-of select="contributor/username"/></created_by>
   </content>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
```

So now to my problems:

1. The XML File Transformation does only partially work. I get all the values I want except for the title.
2. I would like to save the transformed code to a new XML File.

The iteration is necessary because the original file that I want to change is much bigger with much more `<pages>`.

Comment: Re #1, i am not able to reproduce your problem. Re #2, are you doing this in a browser?

Comment: #1 I tried it at the XSLT Tryit Editor from http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog and tehre the title doesnt show up so i thought that it doesn't work.  #2 I am locally working with notepad++.

Comment: How about you try again [here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJF/1) ?

Comment: Wow thanks this solved problem #1 I have no idea why it doesn't work on the webeditor of w3 but great to see that it works. Any suggestions on the second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The XML File Transformation does only partially work. I get all the values I want except for the title. (...) I have no idea why it doesn't work on the webeditor of w3

Never trust any content on w3schools - they are in no way related to W3C, and their tools cannot be expected to be compliant with the specifications. I strongly recommend you never use the site again to test XSLT transformations. At the time of writing, http://xsltransform.net is a great alternative that can be relied upon.

> I would like to save the transformed code to a new XML File.

Looking at the stylesheet reference in your XML document:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTest.xsl"?>
```

it looks like you are currently doing this transformation in the *browser*. All major browsers include an XSLT 1.0 processor, but they will not allow you to save the transformation result as a file. In browsers, transformations are meant to facilitate the *display* of data, not to make *permanent* changes to the document.

To save the output to a file, you need to

- use a command line tool like Saxon
- use an XSLT library and the programming language of your choice to parse an input file, transform it and output the result to a file

---

One last comment on XSLT versions:

Your stylesheet states that the code should use XSLT version 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
```

but currently, no browser supports XSLT 2.0. To use features that are specific to XSLT 2.0 (you don't use any), you need an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer I'll mark my problem as solved

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and I have found that it is possible to use Google Chrome to apply an xslt transformation. I will document the process here since I have already forgotten once how to do so.

Here is an example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sort.xslt"?>

<employees>

  <employee hireDate="04/23/1999">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Phil</first>
    <salary>100000</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee hireDate="09/01/1998">
    <last>Herbert</last>
    <first>Johnny</first>
    <salary>95000</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee hireDate="08/20/2000">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Graham</first>
    <salary>89000</salary>
  </employee>

  <employee hireDate="08/20/2001">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Albert</first>
    <salary>110000</salary>
  </employee>

</employees>
```

And here is the corresponding xslt (sort.xlst):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="employees">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
        <xsl:sort select="salary" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First, place both of them in the same folder. Then launch Google chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag. Then open the xml file in chrome. The xml will be rendered as:

```
Hill Graham 89000 Herbert Johnny 95000 Hill Phil 100000 Hill Albert 110000
```

As you can see, all the xml tags are missing. However, right-click on the page and select "inspect" to launch the developer console. In the developer console, select the "Elements" tab. Right-click on the `<employees>` top level tag and from the menu select "Copy -> Copy outerHTML". Open a new document in your text editor of choice and paste the transformed xml. In my example it looks like this:

```
<employees>
  <employee hireDate="08/20/2000">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Graham</first>
    <salary>89000</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee hireDate="09/01/1998">
    <last>Herbert</last>
    <first>Johnny</first>
    <salary>95000</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee hireDate="04/23/1999">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Phil</first>
    <salary>100000</salary>
  </employee>
  <employee hireDate="08/20/2001">
    <last>Hill</last>
    <first>Albert</first>
    <salary>110000</salary>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

As you can see, the transformed xml has been recovered and can now be saved.